# retrieve id for entry by 2 distinct values

Tags: sql

I have the following relation table

| image_id | type | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CAMERA | aaa |
| 1 | OBJECT | 123 |
| 3 | CAMERA | ccc |
| 3 | OBJECT | 123 |
| 4 | CAMERA | aaa |
| 5 | CAMERA | ddd |
| 5 | OBJECT | 456 |
| 6 | CAMERA | ddd |
| 6 | OBJECT | 789 |

Each **image_id** has a **type** *CAMERA* and some has also **type** *OBJECT*.
Sometimes the camera has detected an object.

I would like to retrieve all the **image_id** which their camera has detected an object (sorry fo my poor english) and the same object has been detected at least by 2 distinct cameras.

From the table the output should be:
1,3,4

1 & 3 => because the camera 'aaa' has detected object 123 and the same object has been detected by camera 'ccc'
4 => because it comes from camera 'aaa'

Comment: Running on hive hadoop. But if you have a solution in mysql or sqlserver it can help. I don't need the exact syntax but the way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicker solutions exist, but this is an intuitive approach you can walk through step-by-step:

```
SELECT 
    image_id
FROM 
    table_name 
WHERE 
    type_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            type_id 
        FROM 
            table_name 
        WHERE 
            type = 'CAMERA' 
            AND image_id IN (
                SELECT 
                    image_id 
                FROM 
                    table_name 
                WHERE 
                    type_id IN (
                        SELECT 
                            type_id 
                        FROM 
                            table_name 
                        WHERE 
                            type = 'OBJECT' 
                        GROUP BY 
                            type_id 
                        HAVING 
                            COUNT(*) > 1
                        )
                )
        )
;
```

Figure out which objects have been seen multiple times; figure out which camera type_ids spotted those objects; and return all the image_ids with those type_ids.